# MySQL, row to column comparison

Tags: mysql

I have two tables; the first one is the pricing based on the country zone and shipment weight.

```
country zone    0.5         1             1.5
a               $5.00        $6.00     $7.00 
b               $8.00        $9.00     $10.00 
c               $11.00   $12.00       $13.00 
d               $14.00   $15.00       $16.00
```

so in this table country zone shows which countries the shipment is coming from and 0.5, 1 and 1.5 are shipment weights

The second table has the country zone and the weights of the shipments

```
country zone        Weight
a                   0.75 
b                   1.20 
c                   1.00 
d                   1.50
```

so what I would like to accomplish is to compare the country zones and weights in the second table to the country zone and weight in the first table, and get the pricing. I think my challenge is here that in the first table the weight columns are numbers and I am not sure how to define the columns and how to compare the rows with the weight columns. If this is confusing here is what I would like to accomplish

```
country zone        Weight   Price
a                   0.75     $5.00 
b                   1.20     $9.00 
c                   1.00     $12.00 
d                   1.50     $16.00
```

some how join these two tables based on the country zone and weight, and get the price. I don't want to use if or select case because the weights can go up to 300 so I may end up having not just 3 columns, but 500 or 600 columns.

I really appreciate your input and if my question is confusing, I apologize for that.

Thank you

Comment: Your first table is really poor design, you should normalize it.

Comment: Some of the weights don't match any of the columns, how are they to be handled?

Comment: I would agree with barmar and say that you should normalize it before spending a lot of time preparing a niche solution for a denormalized table. Perhaps have three columns : countryZone, weight, and price rather than x amount of columns for weight

Comment: I know they don't match, they are not supposed because the shipment may weigh 1.2kg and the price should be in the range of 1.5kg so that's another challenge as well.

Comment: This should be a good starting point - you need to first pivot the rows to columns (assuming you cannot change the table structure directly from the source) http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,75357,75357#msg-75357

Comment: Ok, I will give a try and sorry everyone for the formatting of the first table, I could not align the prices for 1 and 1.5

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback, I am getting there.